# What is a good way to setup a form that supports multiple objects with the same base type?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, mvp

I hava a base type (A) which has two derivatives (B and C). The base type is not abstract. So, I have three objects.

The only difference between B and C is that they both have one extra different property:

- B.Foo
- C.Bar

Now I have conditions like this in my code:

```
if(myObject is B)
     myDatabindB.DataSource = ((B)myReport).Foo);
else if(myObject is C)
     myDatabindC.DataSource = ((C)myReport).Bar);
```

and in another method:

```
pnlSomePanel.Visible = myObject is B;
pnlSomeOtherPanel.Visible = myObject is C;
```

But you can imagine that when there's a new type I have to update all my if-else statements. This violates a lot of OO principles.

But the problem is that I can't think of a nice and clean solution to solve this issue.
Do you have a suggestion / idea to solve this problem?

EDIT:
If it matters, I am using the MVP pattern.

Comment: I imagine it's not this simple to keep to OOP but... If they only have one different property can't you just create a new instance of the same object and null the differing property, for each instance, that they wouldn't use?

Comment: Just clarifying here - you have no control over the base type to change it to abstract?

Comment: @BryanCrosby I do have the control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's good that you asked this with only three items--it makes fixing problems much faster :). Your code's very generic, so I can only offer generic solutions.

The big goal here is to increase the **encapsulation** of classes A, B, and C--to make sure that anything relevant to A, B, or C is stored within those classes and not moved to, say, if-statements elsewhere.

We can move the logic for figuring out what the correct datasource is from the Controller (which is doing your binding) to your report. This method's name should be descriptive, like  GetReportSubjectLine().

```
class A{
    <snip>
    public virtual SomeDataType getDataSourceForViewType(){
     throw new NotImplementedException()
    }
}

class B{
<snip>
public override SomeDataType getDataSourceForViewType(){
    return this.Foo;
    }
}

class C{
 public override SomeDataType getDataSourceForViewType(){
    return this.Bar;
    }
}
```

This code will be reusable if you ever want to make different UI's that still need this type of information from your report to generate whatever graphical view you're generating.

There's no good way around the second problem you presented. We could always move the panel visibility into the reports too, but that increases **coupling**--how much one class is tied to another--way too much. Your reports should not be tied to a specific view.

The best solution is to add another layer of **indirection**--in this case, an intermediary class to handle the logic of what panels to make visible when. This way your controller doesn't have to bear the responsibility of managing panel visibilities itself.

```
public class PanelVisibilityManager{
    ICollection<Panel> ManagedPanels {get; set;}
    //
    public IDictionary<System.Type, ICollection<Panel>> Switchboard {get; set;}

    public void TogglePanelsFor(System.Type item){
        foreach(var panel in ManagedPanels){
            panel.Visible=false;
            }
        foreach(var panel in Switchboard[item]){
                 panel.Visible=true;              
            }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1: For the OP, I would also specify perhaps `IList<IBaseType>` for the `SomeDataType` fields.  Since he is using WinForms, he can use a `BindingList<T>` to easily do databinding.

Answer (score 0):

One the ways to avoid that type of code is move decisional responability into object itself. For example:

Define somewher collection of A.

`List<A> objects = new List<A>{new B(), new C()}`

Instead of having `if/else` use `foreach` over collection and calll on every object a virtual method defined in A and overriden in childs, like

`virtual bool ThisIsMe(A objectToCheck){}`

B and C override this method by checking if `objectToCheck` is their type and return `true` or `false` in regard of it.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
public class A 
{
   public virtual bool ThisIsMe(A objectToCheck){}
   public virtual object GetData{}
}

public class B : A 
{
   public override  bool ThisIsMe(A objectToCheck)
   {   
      return objectToCheck is B;
   }

   public override object GetData()
   {
      return this.Foo;
   }
}

public class C : A 
{
   public override  bool ThisIsMe(A objectToCheck)
   {   
      return objectToCheck is B;
   }

   public override object GetData()
   {
      return this.Bar;
   }
}
```

Now instead of that `if/else`, something like this:

`foreach(A objA in objects)
{
    if(objA.ThisIsMe(myObject))
    {
        myDatabindB.DataSource = objA.GetData();
        break;
    }
}`

May be also substitude this with some fancy `LINQ` instruction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more? I don't understand why to use a List<A>.. And how would you deal with the databinding?

Comment: In this way you have a collection of `A` objects with real types `B` and `C`. So you have a cycle over collection with calling that boolean method for every `A` type which will call the **real** type's method overload.

Comment: @Khelvaster: one of the problems reported by OP is actually avoiding to change `if/else` every time there is a new derived type. Having this structure you should only derive and add the new object of that type to collection. And everything will work without changing anything. So this **does** resolve the problem reported by OP.

Answer (score 0):

[Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) fits here pretty well for the first case

For the second case if you have one to one mapping of your panels you can end up with a static readonly Dictionary<Type, Panel> panels if there are many of types. 
There is a tab control in WinForms to show some particular tab as well

Comment: Thanks and how would you deal with databinding? Every derivative has a bindingsource.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `Dictionary<Type, Action>`?

Then you could do something like this:

```
var myActors = new Dictionary<Type, Action<BaseClass>>();

myActors.Add(typeof(classA), DoSomethingWithA);
myActors.Add(typeof(classB), DoSomethingWithB);

...

Action actor;

if(myActors.TryGetValue(specialRetrievedOnlyAsBase.GetType(), actor))
{
    ResetEverything();
    actor(specialRetrievedOnlyAsBase);
}
else
{
    // ToDo: What should happen if this type is not supported?
}

...

private void DoSomethingWithA(BaseClass)
{
    var classAObject = (ClassA)BaseClass;

    // ToDo: What should happen if classA arrives?
}

private void DoSomethingWithA(BaseClass)
{
    var classAObject = (ClassB)BaseClass;

    // ToDo: What should happen if classB arrives?
}
```